# Merge two arrays in alternate fashion

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to merge to arrays of int type with the same size. Here's my code

```
public class classA
{
static int[] mergeArray(int[] arr1, int arr2[])
{
   int arr3[] = new int[arr1.length+ arr2.length];
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
       arr3[count] = arr1[i];
       count++;
       arr3[count] = arr2[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++){

        System.out.print(arr3[i]);
    }
   return arr3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[] = {4,5,6};
    int arr3[] = mergeArray(arr1,arr2);
}
}
```

When I try printing the numbers in first for loop, it gives me 1,4,2,5,3,6 which the correct output. But, When I try printing it outside the first for loop it gives me output 1,2,3,6,0,0. Can someone help me?
TIA

Comment: You forgot a `count++` after adding the `arr2[i]` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loop, when you copy from `arr2` you need to increment your `count`.

```
arr3[count] = arr2[i];
count++;
```

You could also simplify your code a bit like,

```
static int[] mergeArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length * 2];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        arr3[count++] = arr1[i];
        arr3[count++] = arr2[i];
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

And `print` in `main` like

```
int arr3[] = mergeArray(arr1, arr2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
```

**or** in Java 8+, use a `flatMap` and `IntStream` like

```
static int[] mergeArray(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(arr1[i], arr2[i])).toArray();
}
```

for the same result.

Comment: Elliontt, how don't upvote such a great answer? thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Following your code, you forget to upgrade the count after appending the second value:

```
public class classA
{
static int[] mergeArray(int[] arr1, int arr2[])
{
   int arr3[] = new int[arr1.length+ arr2.length];
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
       arr3[count] = arr1[i];
       count++;
       arr3[count] = arr2[i];
       count++; //////////////// here!
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++){

        System.out.print(arr3[i]);
    }
   return arr3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[] = {4,5,6};
    int arr3[] = mergeArray(arr1,arr2);
}
}
```

> explain:

in you code you do `count++;` just once in the foor loop, but, the foor loop goes from 0 to arr1.length, the is equal to arr3.length/2, it means you forget the half of the values, that's why the 0's appear here, because when you start a new array the defaul value in int[] are 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`arr3[count+1] = arr2[i]` and `count += 2`**  instead.

*It could be easily understood than using count++ twice.*

```
static int[] mergeArray(int[] arr1, int arr2[])
{
   int arr3[] = new int[arr1.length+ arr2.length];
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
       arr3[count] = arr1[i];
       arr3[count+1] = arr2[i]; ///////here
       count+=2; ///////and here
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++){

        System.out.print(arr3[i]);
    }
   return arr3;
}
```

Comment: No no my friend... that's not ok... if he does that, the output will be: 405060

Comment: I just had a test.The output was 142536

Comment: I didn't see the arr3[count+1] = arr2[i]; line, my bad, so plus one haha, I tested wrong. Sorry :)

Comment: That's ok.It could be easily understood than using count++ twice

Comment: sure sure, the confusing was not be award about the other important line

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add two values and then increase the kth value.

```
static int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4,9 };
static int[] array2 = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
private static void mergeArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0,j=0; i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length; i++,j++) {
        arr3[k] = arr1[i];
        arr3[++k] = arr2[j];
        k++;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("arr3: " + arr3[i]);
    }
}
```